# pip checkout svn, git etc. with no setup.py

Tags: pip

I understand that one can use pip to install packages from svn etc. ala:

```
-e svn+http://django-grappelli.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/grappelli#egg=grappelli
```

However, in this case, grappelli has no setup.py, so the installation fails.

How can I achieve something like:

```
svn co http://django-grappelli.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/grappelli ../pinax-env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/grappelli/
```

Yet, putting the command in a pip requirements file, such as project.txt and running

```
pip install -r requirements/project.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to install a python package if there is no stored information about it. Pip relies on `setup.py` to get package's information.

`grappelli` has no `setup.py` in the project, so, unfortunately **it is not possible** to install it via `pip/easy_install`.

PS: It if it really important to you, fork the project and add a `setup.py` (or send them a diff patch). I am sure it will help not only you. Maybe you can take [`django_compressor`](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor/blob/develop/setup.py) as an example.