# Including Git submodules on pythonpath when using virtualenv

Tags: python, django, git, virtualenv, pythonpath

I'm using Git for version control on a Django project.

As much as possible, all the source-code that is not part of the project per se, but that the project depends on, is brought in as Git submodules. These live on a `lib` directory and have to be included on python path. The directory/files layout looks like:

```
.git
docs
lib
my_project
    apps
    static
    templates
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    manage.py
    settings.py
    .gitmodules
README
```

What, would you say, is the best practice for including the libs on python path?

I am using virtualenv, so I could easily sym-link the libraries to the virtualenv's site-packages directory. However, this will tie the virtualenv to this specific project. my understanding is that the virtualenv should not depend on my files. instead, my files should depend on the virtualenv.

I was thinking of using the same virtualenv for different local copies of this project, but if I do things this way I will lose that capability. Any better idea how to approach this?

---

**Update:**

The best solution turned out being to let pip manage all the dependencies.

However, this means not being able to use git submodules, as pip [can't yet handle relative paths properly](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/328). So, external dependencies will have to live on the virtualenv (typically: my_env/src/a_python_module).

I'd still prefer to use submodules, to have some of the dependencies living on my project tree. This makes more sense to me as I've already needed to fork those repos to change some bits of them, and will likely have to change them some more in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dump all your installed packages in a requirement file (requirements.txt looks the standard naming) using

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

everytime you need a fresh virtualenv you just have to do:

```
virtualenv <name> --no-site-packages
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

the install -r requirements.txt works great also if you want to update to newer packages

just keep requirements.txt in sync with your packages (by running pip freeze every time something changes) and you're done, no matter how many virtualenv you have.

NOTE: if you need to do some development on a package you can install that using the -e (editable) param, this way you can edit the package and you don't have to uninstall/install every time you want to test new stuff :)

Comment: This require all my dependencies to be findable by pip, right? Unfortunately, most of them aren't.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia with pip you can install packages from git, svn, mercurial e.g. pip install git+<git-repo>/#egg=Package

Comment: Interesting. Ok, but does it mean I will have to give up on having them as git submodules then?

Comment: @FilipeCorreia you can use both, my suggestion is to not use git submodules as a python package manager since there are tools for that !

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Apparently pip [requires a setup.py to exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701153/pip-checkout-svn-git-etc-with-no-setup-py). One of the projects that I'm using doesn't have a setup.py, but I will try to get the author to add one, in lack of a better option.

Comment: Found a big downside to this approach. I don't intend to touch on most of the external dependencies that I've mentioned, but I need to make  changes to some of them. This means that I will fork and maintain a personal branch of those projects until my changes get merged back into the main repository (eventually). (continued)

Comment: (continuing) The thing is, if I'm not using submodules, I will have to hack on a lib on a different working copy, push those changes to my remote fork, and run a `pip install -r requirements.txt` to have those changes back in my project. If something doesn't work as expected, I will need to make another full roundtrip. Getting feedback takes a quite more that I wish for...

Comment: As an alternative, I tried using git submodules like I described, and add lines to requirements.txt using relative paths. [pip's documentation referes to this](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html), but unfortunately it [doesn't work](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/328), so I'm back at square one.

Comment: @FilipeCorreia Luckly you're wrong about the roundtrip :) with pip you can work on a local copy of a package (if you're doing some development on that package) w/o the need to commit/pull/install to see changes applied. eg. pip install -e git+ssh://path#egg=Package installs Package and checks it out in virtualenv's src folder

Comment: oh, I was assuming that it would pull the files from a Git repo, but that it wouldn't be really a working copy. That means I can hack on it and commit/push files on that dependent repo too?

Comment: I came to exactly the same conclusion after using git submodule and virtualenv/pip.