# Pip ignores changed requirement

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, requirements.txt

The requirements.txt file for a package under development contains something like:

```
git://git.gitsomewhere.com/MyProject.git@da39a3aaae6b4b0d3255bf5595601890afd80709#egg=MyProject
```

And it installs by

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

when there were no previous version.

However, when commit hash changes, pip will not update the dependency (happily reporting that requirement already satisfied).

Is there any way to reliably make pip fetch the right version, specified by commit hash (and maybe further confirmed by version in the setup.py of the fetched package)?

pip 8.1.2, for the record.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add editable project instead of installing into virtualenv by prepending the dependency line with `-e`:

```
-e git://git.gitsomewhere.com/MyProject.git@da39a3aaae6b4b0d3255bf5595601890afd80709#egg=MyProject
```

Another way, which may be preferable under some circumstances is to add (directly or into some more convenient path):

```
-e MyProject
```

and handle as git submodule. (see also [Including Git submodules on pythonpath when using virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492649/including-git-submodules-on-pythonpath-when-using-virtualenv) )

One more way:

```
./MyProject
```

beware, previous solutions may be influenced by old installations.

NB, that `pip install -r requirements.txt` will update installation **only if version** in setup.py **changed**.

Before going with one solution or another, check how (and whether) it recovers from previously installed packages.